# TypeScript: “Parallel” generics?

Tags: typescript, generics

Difficult to find the right wording for my problem, so I’ll get straight to an example. I have two parallel hierarchies of `IMessage` and `IHandler` implementations:

```
interface IMessage {
  type: string;
}

interface IHelloMessage extends IMessage {
  type: 'hello';
}

interface IHandler<M extends IMessage> {
  type: string;
  handle: (message: M) => void;
}

class HelloHandler implements IHandler<IHelloMessage> {
  type = 'hi';
  handle (message: IHelloMessage): void {
    console.log('handle', message);
  }
}
```

A handler is supposed to handle a message of a specific `type`. In above’s example there’s a `IHelloMessage` which has a type `hello` and which is supposed to be handled by `IHelloHandler`.

However, notice, that I’ve accidentally given the type `hi` instead of `hello` in the `HelloHandler`.

Is there any chance to verify these potential errors via TypeScript?

**[edit]** lukasgeiter’s solution works great. Just one minor thing: In my handler classes, I now have to declare the `type` as follows:

```
type: 'hello' = 'hello';
```

When I skip the first `'hello'` I end up with the following error:

> Property 'type' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. ts(2564)

I there any way to avoid the redundancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is use a lookup type to retrieve the type of the property `type` from the generic parameter `M`:

```js
interface IHandler<M extends IMessage> {
  type: M['type'];
  handle: (message: M) => void;
}
```

That way `type` of the class implementing `IHandler` has to match the `type` in the message.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkIGctwOYoDeAUMsmAJ4AOEAXMlmFKHgNzEC+xxoksiKVAAkIAG1EB7TDnwoIAD0ggAJljTTcBZCTKUa9AOQALMZIPsuPcNHhI0QuCtHQAPOmQKlq9dk0QAfNqk5NR0yOgA2gZ6EAYAuuxkRo7KzvQAFAC2vrL06ACUyAC8gQBuEsDKFtwIonA4yCLiEg5O0MjAmVTO2eBqwinOUC7CplI5BIE6ITQAhIZGwObByW3IWRNho80asvn05ZVBZGQIEiBYEs4AdJJ46caDsQA0yNkyBPmJyFwcQA)

---

#### Edit - `type` initialization

When you omit the type like this:

```js
type = 'hello';
```

The compiler will infer its type as `string`, which we don't want. We can prevent this widening of the type by adding [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) after the string literal:

```js
type = 'hello' as const;
```

---

As a more elaborate solution, which I personally would prefer, is to make `IHandler` an abstract class (technically you could also keep the interface and introduce a new abstract class of course):

```js
abstract class Handler<M extends IMessage> {
  constructor(
    public type: M['type']
  ) {}

  abstract handle(message: M): void;
}
```

This way the initialization of the property happens in the `Handler` class and subclasses only have to pass the value to the super constructor:

```js
class HelloHandler extends Handler<IHelloMessage> {
  constructor() {
    super('hello');
  }
  handle (message: IHelloMessage): void {
    console.log('handle', message);
  }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkIGctwOYoDeAUMsmAJ4AOEAXMlmFKHgNzEC+xxoksiKVAAkIAG1EB7TDnwoIAD0ggAJljTTcBZCTKUa9AOQALMZIPsuxOACNGURGGQJRcHMiFwVo6AB50yBSVVdWxNCAA+bVInCRA7AFcEMAkoAAposip461FgBHJqOmR0AG0DPQgDAF1ogEptSzIbOwdkI09lb1SAW1DZenRa+gA3CWBlC25nVzURcQkPL2gAxQgVWY7vKB9hUyk+gkidGLimROS0+uOyLHiaNOM9g1r2Mi4ydqXkHoOi3fmNLIhshRuMomQyAhYlgJN4AHSSPCpYybSoAGmQvRkBBe0S4HCAA)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! I've one little follow-up, which I'll add to above’s question, probably you got an idea :-)

Comment: You're welcome. See the updated answer for the response to your follow-up.

Comment: Awesome! I’m always positively and negatively surprised of how much of TypeScript I don’t know yet!